# Grouping totals by date ranges

Tags: sql

I have to get totals from a table using different criteria, which I do like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  SUM(CASE WHEN MYCONDITION1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MYCONDITION2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL2
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2
WHERE COMMON_CONDITION1 AND COMMON_CONDITION2
AND BETWEEN DATE1 AND DATE2;
```

This works fine and I get the intended result.

Now, I have to repeat this for every week for the last 12 months, excluding holidays period.  So, I generate a set of date ranges which will be used in the queries.  So, I repeat the above sql statement for all the date ranges, which is a lengthy process.

I have to get the totals for every week.  For example from 26-Sep-2010 to 02-Oct-2010, 19-Sep-2010 to 25-Sep-2010, 12-Sep-2010 to 18-Sep-2010, etc.. How should I put those ranges in the query for grouping and in the select list, as I don't have them in a table.

How can I do that in a single shot and get all totals for each date range.  Please help me with sql.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you not use a temporary table containing the ranges and join with that table?

Comment: Which database server are you using? Are you trying to do this in plain SQL? I doubt there is any direct way to get in SQL not only the first day of the week (last one is easy if you have first) but also excluding holidays. This sounds like you need a stored procedure to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table that contains the date ranges.  You can join on the new table; you'll have to replace distinct with group by.  For example:

```
SELECT  TABLE3.DATE1
,       TABLE3.DATE2
,       SUM(CASE WHEN MYCONDITION1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL1
,       SUM(CASE WHEN MYCONDITION2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL2
FROM    TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3
WHERE   COMMON_CONDITION1 
        AND COMMON_CONDITION2
        AND DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN TABLE3.DATE1 AND TABLE3.DATE2
GROUP BY
        TABLE3.DATE1
,       TABLE3.DATE2
```